# Converting event coordinates to component pixel coordinates in Codename One

Tags: codenameone

The coordinates provided with ActionEvent are relative to the screen, while the coordinates for painting a Component are relative to the enclosing Form.

How do I convert event coordinates to paint coordinates when the Form is scrolled?

Answer (score 3):

Pointer information is always relative to the Display, while painting information is always relative to the Form.

Conversion from Display to Form coordinates can be achieved by:

```
x -= getAbsoluteX() - getX();
y -= getAbsoluteY() - getY();
```